# Convert User ID's to User Names in a single.php file

Tags: functions, post-meta

I have a post_meta "thevoters" that store users ids like: 1,2,20 ...etc,
How i can turn this id's to User Names to list them in a single page?

This will echo the numbers as text,

```
echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "thevoters", true);
```

any help?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$thevoters_ids = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "thevoters", true ); // get a comma separated list of ids

$thevoters_ids = explode( ',', $thevoters_ids ); // turn the list into an array

foreach ( $thevoters_ids as $thevoter_id ) { // loop through the ids
    $thevoter = get_user_by( 'id', $thevoter_id ); // get the user object by id
    echo $thevoter->display_name; // display the user name
}
```